# Duration of execution query in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a simple way to know the duration of a query in Cassandra like a `\timing` in PostgreSLQ ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Cqlsh you get the execution time by `TRACING ON`**

Example :

```
TRACING ON
SELECT * FROM exp;
```

You will get the cumulative execution time in microsecond on a specific node in the `source_elapsed` column

Comment: Thank you ! That's exactly what I want !